# Opengl glsl multiple shaders freeze screen

Tags: opengl, glsl

I'm writing a little OpenGl program with Glsl.
Now I have two objects which I need to draw. Both have different shaders.
Normally I think I should do something like that in my draw() method:

```
void draw() {
    shaderObjektOne.bind();
    glBegin(xxx);
      //draw Object one
      ...
    glEnd()
    shaderObjektTwo.bind();
    glBegin(xxx);
      //draw Object two
      ...
    glEnd()
}
```

If I do that this way my screen freezes.
Binding the shader for only one object is working without problems. 
I've been looking around but I couldn't find a real explanation why this error occurs.
Is it because a render target can only be rendered with one shader?
How can I avoid a giant shader file or having multiple render targets?

Thanks.

EDIT:
I want to have separate compiled shader programs for each object. These will be bound right before I draw the vertexes for the object. I want to avoid one big shader in which I need to set specific parameters to choose the functionality for the object. I use glut and currently all drawing is done before  glutSwapBuffers(). 
'Freezing' means that there is actual something visible on the screen (the last object I've drawn with the last bound shader) but my input isn't working anymore. That means, I cannot move the camera in the world but the program is still running normal (tested with a debugger).

Comment: What do you mean by screen freezing? Is the stuff drawn? Is the code infinite looping somewhere? (Also, mixing shaders and immediate mode?)

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo: "mixing shaders and immediate mode" It's certainly possible. It's terrible code, but OpenGL loves backwards compatibility like this...

Comment: Could you implement this as a function with an intermediate glsl file? Then include the others, but use parameters to filter to the desired functionality. Basically, make your two shaders more modular.

Comment: @Mike what do you mean "avoid giant shader file?" You always need 2 shaders for render target. one to draw the scene on a texture and the other one to draw the actual texture

Comment: @MikeSchweizer: This sounds like your shaders just failed to compile. Since you obviously use a legacy context or compatibility profile, the GL will fall back to the fixed-function pipeline. Depending on how you set up your transformations for the shaders, the FFP might completely ignore this. The issue is definitively not in the code part you included so far.

Comment: Both shaders compile fine. It's just like I said: if I bind only one of the two shaders all is working fine. EDIT: Just realized that when I unbind the shader right after I have drawn an object the scene freezes even if I bind it again right before I start to draw. `shader.bind(); drawObject(); shaderUnbind()`.

Comment: @MikeSchweizer: how do you do the transformation state updates? For example, uniforms are per-program state. It is a guesswork unless you provide the relevant source code.

Answer (score 0):

Got it. 
It was a problem with my program design. I accidentally added a copy of the shader which I wanted to bind.
Everytime I tried to bind the shader it bound the copy of it.

Thanks for your help guys :)